# How onChange checkbox after checked based on index and selected 1 by 1

Tags: reactjs

I have the data, i need to select it in checkbox but on my function onChange when im select the box, all of the list is selected, how to do select item 1 by 1 based on their index

i dont have any idea, how to select by their index, can someone help me ?

```
const data = [
    {
        item    : 'HKK50_BBJ',
        qty     : 2,
        sell    : '28754',
        buy     : '-',
        avail   : 2,
        date    : '2019-07-08'
    }
];

for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    data.push(data[0]);
};


class OpenPositions extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            newArr : [],
            checked: false,

        };
    }


    handleCheckBox(index){
        console.log(index);
        this.setState({
            checked : !this.state.checked
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{height:'100%', overflow:'auto'}}>
                <table className="borderline" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style={{height:'100%'}}>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <div>       
                                        <table style={{height:"100%", width:"100%"}}>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr align="center" className="fieldtitle fieldbg">
                                                    <td align="left">Items</td>
                                                    <td>Qty</td>
                                                    <td>Sold</td>
                                                    <td>Bought</td>
                                                    <td>Avail</td>
                                                    <td>Date</td>
                                                    <td>Options</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>

                                            <tbody className="divOP2">

                                                        {data.map((item, index) =>{
                                                            console.log(item, "ini item bois");
                                                            console.log(index, "ini index")
                                                            return(
                                                            <tr align="center" className="contentbg">
                                                                <td align="left" nowrap className="bggradientleft"><font color="#FFFFFF"><strong>{item.product}</strong></font></td>
                                                                <td>{item.qty}</td>
                                                                <td>{item.sell}</td>
                                                                <td>{item.buy}</td>
                                                                <td>{item.avail}</td>
                                                                <td>{item.date}</td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <input
                                                                        className="checkbox"
                                                                        type="checkbox"
                                                                        checked={this.state.checked}
                                                                        onChange={this.handleCheckBox.bind(this, index)}
                                                                    />
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        )})}                
                                            </tbody>                        
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <table className="normal" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style={{height:'100%'}}>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="submit" className="normalButton wide">GTC Order (Liq)</button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="submit" className="normalButton wide" onClick={this.handleBuySellLiq.bind(this)}>Buy/Sell (Liq)</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

i expect to select the checkbox 1 by 1 by their index, i dont know how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a checked property to each Object in the `data`:

```
{
    item    : 'HKK50_BBJ',
    qty     : 2,
    sell    : '28754',
    buy     : '-',
    avail   : 2,
    date    : '2019-07-08',
    checked : false,
}
```

And then:

```
handleCheckBox(index) {
  console.log(index);
  const itemToChange = this.state.newArr[index];
  itemToChange.checked = !itemToChange.checked;
  const newArray = [...this.state.newArr];
  newArray[index] = itemToChange;
  this.setState({
    newArr: newArray,
  })
}
```

---

#### UPDATE:

> Here's a [**Working Sample CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/check-only-the-selected-checkbox-ox4f1) for your ref.